# start elasticmq server and access it

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have started elasticmq server which runs in my localhost. But when I access it with the browser localhost:9324 it is showing error message as

```
Request is missing required form field 'Action'
```

So how can I access it in the browser. Please help.

Comment: Isn't there something in the protocol that needs to be sent to the server? Smells like just opening the HTTP address doesn't do the trick. Have you tested a elasticmq client on it?

Comment: I have sent the http protocol to the elastic server. I am calling the elasticmq with right_aws in my ruby application. And I have given it as sqs = RightAws::SqsGen2.new("AKIA","bWksa23",:server=>"localhost",:port=>9324,:protocol=>"http")